# Where to invoke a jar file (ATM)after a json generated in reports in cucumber framework?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Scenario:

Automation Framework :
Cucumber framework using MAVEN
Scenario-->test executed-->now a json file is generated in cucumber reports--->Now this json file path needs to be provided to the jar file to run (ITS FUNCTION IS--raise tickets in JIRA).

Issue: When i put jar file execution in the @after method--->then it gives error because the json is not yet generated.

NOTE: It seems that json in the cucumber report will be generated only after all the execution and BUILD SUCCESS.
THAT'S why when i am passing the json path in the after method it is not taking.

Please suggest where to invoke this jar which is dependent on the json report generated.

Comment: Create a jvm shutdown hook and access the json inside it.

Answer (score 1):

@akhouri: If you are using Jenkins for operating your project, then you can use Post-build Actions with plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin to run your jar file.